# C# "Local" variable loaded inside a task won't keep its value when called outside the task

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, scope, task

I'm running in circles with this one. I have some tasks on an HttpClient (.NET 4 with httpclient package from NuGet), in one of them i'm trying to assign a value to a variable that i declared OUTSIDE the task, at the beggining of the function, but when the execution gets to that point, the variable lost the assigned value and came back to the initial value, like it never changed. But I'm pretty sure it DID change at a moment, when the execution passed through the task.

I've made this screenshot to show it more easily:

[image]

What should I do to make my xmlString KEEP the value that was assigned to it inside the task, and use it OUTSIDE the task???

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: If your task computes a result it should assign that result to its `Result`, rather than mutating a closed over variable.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your screenshot (it would be better if you provided the code in your question as well) you are never awaiting your task.  Therefore, your last usage where you obtain the value of `xmlString` happens *before* your task has finished executing, and presumably before your `.ContinueWith()` has assigned the variable.

Ideally, your enclosing method should be async as well.  Then you can simply `await` it.  Otherwise, you can try calling the `.ContinueWith(...).Wait()` method first, though at that point your'e not leveraging async semantics at all.

Comment: Also, `Wait()` can deadlock.

Comment: @SLaks, yes, I know, with infinite sadness and frustration. :)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `await`? It makes the code a lot cleaner.
Replace the `client.GetAsync()` line with the following:

`HttpResponse resp = await client.GetAsync(par);`

And then add the try-catch part of the Task. Then it should work as you originally intended it to!

EDIT:

Servy is half-right in the comments. Apart from the [Microsoft.Net.HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) you will most probably need to manually add [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) too.

Comment: And the HttpClient package. Which, AFAIQ, even on 4.0, contains the async definitions.

Comment: That means he'd have the async methods, but not use of the `await` keyword.

Comment: Those two come together and you can't have one without the other. An async method if called, requires an `await` on it, except if it returns null. And if you use `await`, the method it is in will need to be async too.

Comment: In fact, last time I helped out a friend of mine with async stuff in 4.0, it automatically grabbed the MS [Async Targeting Pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx) which made it possible to use await.

Comment: No, they *don't* come together.  C# had plenty of asynchronous metohds leveraging tasks before C# 5.0 ever came out.  Just because you have libraries using async methods doens't mean you have access to `await`.  Additionally, you don't *need* to use `await` to write asynchronous methods.  You can always do it the way everyone did it before `await` existed, namely manually adding your own continuations.

Comment: Exactly. Await keyword isn't available.

Comment: From what i'm guessing, the variable has the original value because the streamTask never ended its execution??

Comment: Exactly. It is running parallel to the task he has included in ContinueWith(), so when the app gets to assigning resp, it gets an empty HttpResponseMessage.